# Running unverified app on mac

Tags: macos, applications, permission

I am on macOS Catalina. On a site they say that, if I am having problems, in order to be able to run the app I need to input (sudo chown -R 755 AppName.app) in the terminal. My question is: is it safe to do so? Is there a way to reverse my actions?

Comment: The command you list doesn't solve the problem of running unverified applications. Which application is this, where do you download it from, which error message to you get when running it? And which site (link) proposed to run `chmod ...` to enable unverified applications?

Comment: This is the link: https://web.archive.org/web/20181228073723/https://macgames-download.com/tutorials/

Comment: I do not get any error messages, the app is not starting. I remember solving the problem with this method on macOS High Sierra. I just wanted to make sure I am not screwing anything.

Comment: Simple put, NO it is not safe to follow those directions. `chown` changes ownership. `chmod` changes the permission bits.

Comment: @dsad you can run `man chown` which will open the manual page of the command and read it. Try running the app by right click > open **IF** you're sure that you want to run it.